# How do I convert english words to local language using c#

Tags: .net

**can we translate the English words in to local or regional language in standalone windows application?**
please let me know if any one know about it....thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible via globalization you must provide your application with language resource

you will add the main language it will have all the world in your app and other language will add in different  files like so

lang.resx => main file

lang.fr-Fr.resx => other language

lang.en-US.resx => other language

for more help

[Introduction to Localization and Globalization in .NET](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/intro-to-localization-globalization-dotnet)

[MSDNglobalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: but, can we do it for stand alone windows application?